# Как решить вопрос с индексацией страниц?

Tags: seo, поисковые-системы

У меня таких страниц около 112 тысяч
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо проверить следующее:

1. Выдерживает ли сервер, на котором размещен сайт, нагрузку (подробнее тут https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7440203#discovered__unclear_status).
2. Можно ли считать контент размещенный на страницах не приемлемым с точки зрения правил Google? Смотрите абзац на той же странице "These pages are typically not indexed, and we think that is appropriate. These pages are either duplicates of indexed pages, or blocked from indexing by some mechanism on your site, or otherwise not indexed for a reason that we think is not an error."